# viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear never get called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I created my own class for PopoverController (Without subclassing UIPopoverController) to present ViewControllers in the way i want.

CustomPopoverController is NOT a UIViewController, instead it has an ivar called "contentViewController" which is the VC that will actually be displayed.

I implemented my own "dismissPopoverAnimated:" to dismiss my custom popover when the user tap anywhere outside the contentViewController's frame:

```
-(void) dismissPopoverAnimated : (BOOL) animated
{
     // dismissalView is the view that intercept the taps outside.
    [self.dismissalView removeFromSuperview];
    self.dismissalView = nil;
    if (animated)
    {
        CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
        // When in landscape Mode the width of the screen is actually the "height"
        newFrame.origin.y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                         animations:^{self.view.frame = newFrame;} 
         completion: ^(BOOL finished) {if(finished) [self.contentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];}];
    }
    else 
    {
        [self.contentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    isPresented = NO;
    [self.delegate customPopoverDidDismissPopover:self];
}
```

The problem is, that even though `removeFromSuperView` is called in any case - animated or not, the `contentViewController` never receives either `viewWillDisappear`, `viewDidDisappear` or even `viewDidUnload` when i'm releasing the `contentViewController`;

Does anyone have an idea why?
Or even better throw some light on the chain of viewWill.../viewDid... method and when they supposed to be called.

Comment: If CustomPopoverController is NOT a UIViewController.. then what is CustomPopoverController? `self.contentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];` I think will call the viewWillDisappear in ContentViewController

Comment: @7KV7 - CustomPopoverController is my own class, derived directly from NSObject. And my problem is viewWillDisappear is NOT called in contentViewController as expected. That's exactly what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you add subview or remove subview by the methods of UIView, it never cause owned `UIViewController` call `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillDisappear`, and `viewDidDisapper`. Only those viewController managed by the method of `UINavigationController`, like `pushViewController:animated:` or `popViewControllerAnimated:`, or `presentModelViewController:aniamted:` ... etc. They will notify about the status is changing for the view of controller.

Comment: This is a bit surprising since it is not mentioned in the documentation. do you have any link for the source f this knowledge?

Comment: No, I have no link. I tried many times because some of my view was  composed of the views belong to another UIViewController. When doing view transition by adding the view of another UIViewController, it needs to call viewWillAppear:animated:, viewWillDisappear:animated, and ... etc manually. Because the UIViewController is not managed by UINavigationController or something else. The UIView appears or disappear on the screen, it will call willMoveToWindow: . When appearing, the parameter is not nil; and when disappearing, the parameter of UIWindow is nil. The apple's document has said that.

Comment: @Toro in my experience viewWillAppear: is called always even when manual control of UIView, but viewWillDisappear: is not called in this case really. Could you give minimal example when viewWillAppear: is not called?

Comment: For example, there are `A` and `B` UIViewControllers. And now `view` of `A` is appeared, then call `[A.view addSubView:B.view]`. Does `viewWillAppear` of `B` be called ?