# viewWillDisappear, viewWillUnload viewDidUnload never called

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

The methods on my root viewController `viewWillDisappear, viewWillUnload viewDidUnload` never get called (have log statements in each).

Seems like this has come up before here but the answers are not entirely clear. This one seems to imply that the viewController view needs to be embedded in a `UINavigationController` which seems odd and not something I have seen mentioned anywhere else.

[viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear never get called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894576/viewwilldisappear-and-viewdiddisappear-never-get-called)

If this is the case, where else can I do some cleanup and insure that my UIDocument changes get saved?

**EDIT:** Guess I misunderstood @ how the root viewController events work (it's unique status, etc). Will look into the AppDelegate methods. Just trying to make sure that my UIDocument stuff gets saved and also that my Core Audio stuff gets closed down correctly.

**Close:**
Ended up going with notifications posted by the AppDelegate. Seems to work pretty well + simple stuff after you do it once.

// from the appDelegate

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"handleCleanup" 
                                                    object: nil 
                                                  userInfo: nil];
}
```

and my VC registering for the notification:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self 
                                         selector: @selector(saveAndCleanup) 
                                             name: @"handleCleanup" 
                                           object: nil];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's your root view, and you never change it - then it's not going to disappear. Although, viewWillDisapear may get called when you put your app to the background - I can't remember.

You're view controller will only get unloaded if you receive a memory warning, but if it's onscreen - it won't get unloaded.

viewWillDisappear:

> This method is called in response to a view being removed from a view hierarchy. This method is called before the view is actually removed and before any animations are configured.

viewDidUnload:

> When a low-memory condition occurs and the current view controller’s views are not needed, the system may opt to remove those views from memory. This method is called after the view controller’s view has been released and is your chance to perform any final cleanup. If your view controller stores separate references to the view or its subviews, you should use this method to release those references. You can also use this method to remove references to any objects that you created to support the view but that are no longer needed now that the view is gone. You should not use this method to release user data or any other information that cannot be easily recreated.

Comment: doh! That makes sense. I am testing in the Simulator and was expecting to see those view events get triggered. Seem like the AppDelegate is the correct place to handle my cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

A typical place to release unnecessary cache or resources is `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning`. If you didn't do so in this method, iOS may choose to kill your app when in low memory.

Considering the nature of mobile apps, you should save as often as possible. Typical implementation uses timer to issue automatic saving. Sometimes a call comes in, iOS may choose to kill your app instead of putting it into the background because you are using a lot of memory.

On another note, when `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` is called, it's certain that your view will be unloaded. This, however, doesn't mean the app will be killed. It means the next time the app is opened, `viewDidLoad` will be called again. In such sense, you can try and save the file in this method.