# viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear and viewWillDisappear not being called on iOS 5 when using setViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I'm setting a ViewController using the following code: `[detailNav setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:vc] animated:NO];`

When the ViewController is set in iOS 6 and 7, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear and viewWillDisappear is called.

However, in iOS 5, these methods are not called.

Edit: pushViewController does not work either: 
[viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear never get called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894576/viewwilldisappear-and-viewdiddisappear-never-get-called)

Comment: did you make certain to set the delegate of those view controllers you are adding?

Comment: Post some more code. I am rather certain `UINavigationController` does call these methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out somewhere in the ViewControllers hierarchy, `automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers` was returning `NO`.

Returning `YES` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark but make sure each has the super call example in the viewdidload method it would have this first

[super viewDidLoad];